# 2 of my softphones cannot register to Asterisk

Tags: centos, centos-7, asterisk

I just installed Asterisk 15.2.2 on a CentOs 7 VM. I installed Ekiga and I'm trying to connect *Albert* with registrar **localhost:5065**.
I have a second VM (Ubuntu) with Ekiga too. I'm trying to connect *Alice* with registrar: **192.168.182.130:5065**
And on my host machine (Windows 10), I'm using X-Lite and I managed to connect *John* with the same registrar as *Alice*.

I don't understand why *John* is the only one being able to connect to Asterisk.

First, I used the default port (5060) and thus I didn't specified it in the registrar. But only *Albert* could register... So I changed the port but it's still not working.
I disabled my CentOs (where Asterisk Server is running)'s firewall.

Any idea to help me :) ?

Thanks in advance,

OoTsun.